# How to configure nginx for node express and Grpc microservices?

Tags: node.js, nginx, grpc

I have this problem to solving:

I should use nginx for comunications between my microservices, but I don't know where I can start.
I use node express for comunications between client (es. react ap) and two microservice in Grpc.

I'm not able for comunicate with my express node and grpc.
How could I write  my file config nginx ?

I have write this for now :

```
upstream api {
 server api:80;
}

upstream exchange{
server exchange:9001;
}

upstream users{
  server users:9002
}

server {
  listen 8080;

     location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      proxy_pass api;
   }   

   location /excahgne{
     grpc_pass excahgne
   }

   location /users{
     grpc_pass users
   }
```

}

How should I route traffic from the epress endpint to the grpc client?

```
es endpoit 
  app.get("/exchange",(req,res)=>{
  
        clientGrpc.exchange(call,callback=>{
            operations..........
             res.send(data)
        }
  }
```

I RECEIVE ALWAYS "No connection established".

I can get into the enpoint, but not the grpc microservice.

Help me please

Comment: Fixing the typo in `location /excahgne` would be a good first step.